# Play Framework 2.3.3 : WS library is slow

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I am migrating my application from Play 2.1.2 to Play 2.3.3( using Play for Java).  I am noticing that web services are slow. These are SOAP services. A basic service was taking 35ms in Play version 2.1.2, is now taking 240ms in Play 2.3.3

Initial Code in Play 2.1.2

```
    WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url(url);
    requestHolder.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_XML_UTF_8_SAVE);
    F.Promise<WS.Response> responsePromise = requestHolder.post(new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    response = responsePromise.get(50000L);
    return response;
```

New Code is Play 2.3.3

```
    WSRequestHolder requestHolder = WS.url(url);
    requestHolder.setHeader(CONTENT_TYPE, CONTENT_TYPE_XML_UTF_8_SAVE);
    F.Promise<WSResponse> responsePromise = requestHolder.post(new ByteArrayInputStream(request.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    response = responsePromise.get(50000L);
    Document responseDoc = null;
    if(response.getStatus() == 200) {
        responseDoc = response.asXml();
    }else{
        Logger.error("service call failed. Status: " + response.getStatus());
    }
    return responseDoc;
```

All setting are the default setting. Am I missing a setting? Does new Play require any settings related to Thread pool? I tried few combinations but did not see any improvement.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Jaswinder

Answer (score 0):

You're calling get with a 50000 millisecond timeout.  That is what is making it slow.  Try using the default get() and use a map() as shown in the examples in https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaWS.

Comment: Will- I changed the code to use map but that did not improve the performance. Then I further changed the post of the body  from InputStream  to String and that did it.